# What is the meaning .External_Conten_URI in given String Code

Tags: android, android-intent, android-sqlite

I am trying to pick a image from Gallery in android but i am not able to understand the purpose of  EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI in given String.
can please elaborate this for me, and i don't know much about the android.

android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI` will return images that are located in the "primary" external storage, while `INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI` will return images from the primary internal storage.

Both of these are not directly related to **memory**, they do not point to internal and external memory.

**internal storage** is the storage your app is allowed to use, other programs can not access this storage.

**external storage** is the storage that everyone can access and use.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is helpful